# Sending html input value only for mobile devices using CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, media-queries

The goal is to send a hidden input value to the server only when coming from a mobile device. I wanted to use CSS media queries so that it stays responsive.

I tried this so far:

**Not displaying the field**

```
<input type='hidden' name='mobile' value='yes' style="display:none">
```

Result: still sent to server

**CSS content**

```
<div class='mobile-only'></div>

@media (max-width: 768px) { 
   .mobile-only {content: "<input type='hidden' name='mobile' value='yes'>"}
}
```

Result: not sent to server at all

Is the non-JS, CSS approach even possible?

Comment: You are better off disabling the field or not even sending it to the browser if not on mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix in some javascript and get it done. Here's something you'd like to take a look at -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        @media (max-width: 768px) { 
           #mymobileelement {display:none;}
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function setvalue () {
            var ele = document.getElementById("mymobileelement");
            var isVisible = ele.offsetWidth > 0 || ele.offsetHeight > 0;
            document.getElementById("ValueToSendToServer").value = (isVisible) ? "pc" : "mobile";
            alert("Server will recieve = " + document.getElementById("ValueToSendToServer").value);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:setvalue();" value="Click me to see what server will get">
    <input type="hidden" value="pc" id="ValueToSendToServer">
    <div id="mymobileelement"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 .mobile-only {content: "<input type='hidden' name='mobile' value='yes'>"}
```

This is invalid code - the `content` attribute is [only valid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) on the `::before` and `::after` pseudoelements. However, even if you fix that it will not work, since the `content` attribute will only insert text, not 'more elements' as you are trying to do now.

There is no solution for your problem this way. Not only should CSS never have influence on behaviour like this, but it would also be highly unreliable - I can resize my desktop browser to 500px wide no problem.

You will need JS to achieve this effect, but even then it will remain unreliable, like anything coming from a client.